# "log" function in "dart:developer" package isn't working in Flutter v3.10.1

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, logging, sdk

Recently, I've upgraded my Flutter SDK to version 3.10.1 (the latet available), and after upgrading I noticed that the "log" function in "dart:developer" isn't working at all.

One can ask why would I need such a function, there are many great packages that provide logging perfectly! I agree, but the "log" function has a great benefit, which is logging the entire provided value in one single console line, this makes the performance much better and faster than going through every single line and then printing them out.

Any alt solutions?

Comment: "the `log` function has a great benefit, which is logging the entire provided value in one single console line...." Huh?  Isn't that the default behavior for `print` or `debugPrint`?

Comment: @jamesdlin definitely isn't the same behavior, when logging very long string values, the default print or debugPrint will print out each line of that string value one by one to the console and you can notice that by seeing the lines always starts with a prefixed value "flutter:", in the other hand, the "log" function prints out the entire value in one single console line which is much faster and better.